# What event is being referenced in the acknowledgements section of The Rise of Endymion?

Tags: dan-simmons, hyperion-cantos

In the French edition (Pocket) of *The Rise of Endymion*, written by Dan Simmons, the acknowledgements section refers to Jeff Orr with the following (my translation):

> Jeff Orr, extraordinaire cybercowboy, for recovering from cyber-space
> forty pages of this story, kidnapped by the TechnoCore;

The book has been written (published?) in 1997. I am not at all familiar with how writers used to write at that time, but could it be that Dan Simmons lost some pages of this story on a computer/Internet and Jeff Orr got it back for him?

Answer (score 2):

Having read books at the time and of that type, I would certainly read it as a humorous expression of gratitude for having recovering, by technical means, forty pages that Simmons had lost through some quirk of software.

TechnoCore was a conglomerate of Artificial Intelligences within the book series, and so a humorous reference to the software.

(Incidentally, I usually hear it called the Acknowledgements section.)

Comment: Oh, interesting. I usually hear it called the Acknowled*gm*ents section 